# selectionchanged event fires twice for xtype selection

Tags: extjs, aem

Recently i noticed that the **selectionchanged** event fires twice when using the selection widget ([CQ.form.Selection](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/widgets-api/?class=CQ.form.Selection)). The selectionchanged is fired once when i select some value from the dropdown, and again when the focus is lost from the selection widget after the selection has been made(i.e., onblur).

The following is the structure of the dialog.

```
<dialog jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog" title="Test Component" xtype="panel">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <title jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldLabel="Selection" name="./sel" type="select" xtype="selection">
            <listeners jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" selectionchanged="function(comp, val, isChecked) {console.log("selected");}"/>
            <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                <opt1 jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="Option 1" value="1"/>
            <opt2 jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="Option 2" value="2"/>
            <opt3 jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="Option 3" value="3"/>
            </options>
        </title>
        <link jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" fieldLabel="Some Text" name="./text" xtype="textfield"/>
    </items>
</dialog>
```

This issue is observed only when the Selection is of type **select** or **combobox** and not checkbox and radio.

Am i implementing it wrong? Is this behavior normal? How to make sure that selectionchanged event is triggered only once?

Thanks in advance!

P.S: I am using CQ 5.5, and am not sure if this behavior is the same in the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using xtype combo and use the change event this makes sure that event gets triggered just once. I am pretty sure this will work, I have tried in CQ 5.6.1. Here is docs http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/widgets-api/?class=CQ.Ext.form.ComboBox.

If you look into the code of Selection.js in crx de /libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/widgets/form/Selection.js There are two custom events fireComboboxSelectionChanged and fireComboboxContentChanged, fireComboboxSelectionChanged gets triggered when  selection happens and fireComboboxContentChanged gets triggered when change happens. Now if we take a look in the extjs documentation the change gets triggered just before blur happens http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox-event-change so ideally it looks that there are two separate events here. But if you take look in the code both fireComboboxSelectionChanged and fireComboboxContentChanged triggers a common event this.fireEvent(CQ.form.Selection.EVENT_SELECTION_CHANGED, hence the event gets fired twice I guess. Again this is just my initial guess from the code I will suggest you to put debug points in the code and use debugClientLibs=true to findout if this is really the cause. I might be wrong and still a learner in CQ, answering based on my reasoning. So please get this verified yourself by debugging in javascript. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is not about making things work :) It is about knowing the issue. Combo might work, but my question is why selection is behaving this way? And how to fix this in selection.

Comment: Even i noticed the same. Will check once again before concluding this might be the reason. Thank you.